# SSH fails with 'Received disconnect' only for select users

Tags: linux, ssh, login, administrator

I have the following issue:

when trying to ssh to a remote server using a specific user, the response from the server is

> Received disconnect from ***: 11:
>
> Disconnected from ***

if I try connecting with a random user name or root, the server responds (normally, I assume!) by asking for the password

> root@***'s password:

If I attempt connections using lftp or sftp, the same happens: the connection is dropped right away for the select user
This makes me wonder whether the users in question where blacklisted on the server. Is this possible? What else could be the cause for this strange behavior?

Added to that, here's another strange fact: if trying to ftp to the remote server using a ftp client (e.g. FileZilla) the connection is accepted! Could it be a protocol issue?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: How does the verbose log look like? `ssh -vvv user@host`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I looked into the debug info and it seems there was an incompatibility with my public keys. I had to remove id_rsa and id_rsa.pub and it worked. Basically, something was forcing the authentification using public key instead of the password... Why would that happen?

Comment: I had to either delete the public key files or force the lftp to ignore pubkey authentication via ssh (the debug showed that ssh was first trying to connect with the pubkey). I guess there were a series of rejected attempts using the pubkey before the server decided to break the connection so the password auth would never kick in.

Answer (score 5):

Yes user level blocking is very much possible via `sshd` configuration

File is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`DenyUsers Arjun@hostname`

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Check the /home directory permissions. It should be

- `drwxr-xr-x.   9 root root   113 Jun 28 22:57 home`

and then your home directory detail:

- `drwxr-----   5  user group   124 May 18 17:00 User
   drwx------  2 user group   29 May 18 12:05 .ssh
   -rw-------  1 user group 2235 Jun 28 23:09 authorized_keys`

**My error messages in logs**

**/var/log/secure** > sshd[22565]: error: Received disconnect from X.X.X.X: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]

**On client side**

`ssh user@X.X.X.X
  Permission denied (publickey).
ssh -vvv user@X.X.X.X
  ...
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
  Permission denied (publickey).`


**On server side**

- `service sshd stop`
- run sshd debug mode:
- `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd`

  `...
        debug1: trying public key file /home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
        debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
   ...`